# mongodb find query filter where a property is at least equal to one of the items in array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

So I am using mongodb as database and I am trying to make find query where a property called "for" value is at least equal to one of the items in array
like this:
    `Model.find({property: {$someMongoLogic: [item1, item2]}})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$in` operator:

```js
Model.find({property: {$in: [item1, item2]}})
```

Comment: how can I send it in request?

Comment: This is the pure mongo query, I am not clear what do you want.